# SSIS 2012 Create environment variable fails

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis, sql-variant-property

I'm working a script to port an Environment from one server to another. I am running into an issue calling `catalog.create_environment_variable` wherein I get the error "The data type of the input value is not compatible with the data type of the 'String'." coming out of the proc "check_data_type_value."

What's strange is that if I let the GUI script out the variables, that query would work

```
DECLARE @var sql_variant = N'\\myserver\ssisdata'
EXEC [catalog].[create_environment_variable]
    @variable_name = N'FolderBase'
,   @sensitive = False
,   @description = N''
,   @environment_name = N'Development'
,   @folder_name = N'POC'
,   @value = @var
,   @data_type = N'String'
GO
```

However, taking this script approach isn't working. The legwork I've done indicates this error message is usually resolved by using nvarchar data type instead of varchar. However, that's not the case for my stuff.

Line 108 for the following script. My assumption is that it's something wonky with the [sql_variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) but I have no idea *what* that thing is.

```
USE SSISDB;
GO

DECLARE
    @folder_id bigint
,   @folder_name nvarchar(128) = N'POC'
,   @environment_name nvarchar(128) = N'Development'
,   @environment_description nvarchar(1024)
,   @reference_id bigint
,   @variable_name nvarchar(128)
,   @data_type nvarchar(128)
,   @sensitive bit
,   @value sql_variant
,   @description nvarchar(1024);

IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM catalog.folders AS F WHERE F.name = @folder_name
)
BEGIN
    EXECUTE catalog.create_folder
        @folder_name = @folder_name
    ,   @folder_id = @folder_id OUTPUT;

    PRINT CONCAT('Folder "', @folder_name, '" has been created with a folder_id of ', @folder_id)
END

IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM catalog.environments AS E WHERE E.name = @environment_name 
    AND E.folder_id = (SELECT F.folder_id FROM catalog.folders AS F WHERE F.name = @folder_name)
)
BEGIN
    PRINT CONCAT('Creating environment ',  @environment_name);

    EXECUTE catalog.create_environment
        @folder_name = @folder_name
    ,   @environment_name = @environment_name
    ,   @environment_description = @environment_description;
END

DECLARE
    @EnvironmentVariables TABLE
(
    folder_name nvarchar(128)
,   environment_name nvarchar(128)
,   variable_name nvarchar(128)
,   description nvarchar(1024)
,   data_type nvarchar(128)
,   sensitive bit
,   value sql_variant
);

INSERT INTO
    @EnvironmentVariables
SELECT
    E.folder_name
,   E.environment_name
,   S.name
,   S.description
,   S.type
,   S.sensitive
,   S.value
FROM
(
    SELECT 'FolderBase','Root for ssis processing','String',CAST(0 AS bit),'\\myserver\ssisdata'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'AuditConnectionString','Conn to audit db','String',CAST(0 AS bit),'Data Source=SQLETL01;Initial Catalog=Audit;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;'
) AS S (name, description, type, sensitive, value)
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        E.name AS environment_name
    ,   F.name AS folder_name
    FROM
        catalog.folders AS F
        INNER JOIN
            catalog.environments AS E
            ON E.folder_id = F.folder_id
    WHERE
        F.name = @folder_name
        AND E.name = @environment_name
) E;


DECLARE Csr CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR
SELECT
    EV.variable_name
,   EV.description
,   EV.data_type
,   EV.sensitive
,   EV.value
FROM
    @Environmentvariables AS EV;

OPEN Csr;
FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO
    @variable_name
,   @description
,   @data_type
,   @sensitive
,   @value;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
            -- THERE BE MONSTERS AHEAD
        -- The data type of the input value is not compatible with the data type of the 'String'. 
        EXECUTE catalog.create_environment_variable
            @variable_name = @variable_name
        ,   @sensitive = @sensitive
        ,   @description = @description
        ,   @environment_name = @environment_name
        ,   @folder_name = @folder_name
        ,   @value = @value
        ,   @data_type = @data_type
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 
            @folder_name        AS folder_name
        ,   @environment_name   AS environment_name
        ,   @variable_name      AS variable_name
        ,   @data_type          AS data_type
        ,   @sensitive          AS sensitive
        ,   @value              AS value
        ,   @description        AS description
        ,   ERROR_NUMBER()AS error_number --returns the number of the error.
        ,   ERROR_SEVERITY() AS error_severity --returns the severity.
        ,   ERROR_STATE()AS error_state  --returns the error state number.
        ,   ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS error_procedure --returns the name of the stored procedure or trigger where the error occurred.
        ,   ERROR_LINE() AS error_line --returns the line number inside the routine that caused the error.
        ,   ERROR_MESSAGE() AS error_message; --returns the complete text of the error message. The text includes the values supplied for any substitutable parameters, such as lengths, object names, or times.

    END CATCH  

    FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO
        @variable_name
    ,   @description
    ,   @data_type
    ,   @sensitive
    ,   @value;
END

CLOSE Csr;
DEALLOCATE Csr;
```

Comment: Son. I am disappoint.

Comment: @swasheck Do you realize how much pride was swallowed before I could click the Submit button?

Comment: I'm not disappoin, you just saved my night.  Freaking nVarChar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"The legwork I've done indicates this error message is usually resolved by using nvarchar data type instead of varchar. However, that's not the case for my stuff." Or *is* it the case?

I made two changes to my cursor. The first is in my CATCH block. I re-read the article on the sql_variant data type and followed with the [sql_variant_property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx). I added a call to that in my catch block, expecting to see `nvarchar` but lo and behold, it reports back `varchar` as my BaseType.

Knowing that and that all of my source data is character based, I cheated and added the `@local` variable with an explicit cast to nvarchar and it magically works.

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        -- THERE BE MONSTERS AHEAD
        -- The data type of the input value is not compatible with the data type of the 'String'. 
        DECLARE
            @local nvarchar(4000) = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000), @value);
        EXECUTE catalog.create_environment_variable
            @variable_name = @variable_name
        ,   @sensitive = @sensitive
        ,   @description = @description
        ,   @environment_name = @environment_name
        ,   @folder_name = @folder_name
        ,   @value = @local
        ,   @data_type = @data_type
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 
            @folder_name        AS folder_name
        ,   @environment_name   AS environment_name
        ,   @variable_name      AS variable_name
        ,   @data_type          AS data_type
        ,   @sensitive          AS sensitive
        ,   @value              AS value
        ,   SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@value, 'BaseType') As BaseType
        ,   @description        AS description
        ,   ERROR_NUMBER()AS error_number --returns the number of the error.
        ,   ERROR_SEVERITY() AS error_severity --returns the severity.
        ,   ERROR_STATE()AS error_state  --returns the error state number.
        ,   ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS error_procedure --returns the name of the stored procedure or trigger where the error occurred.
        ,   ERROR_LINE() AS error_line --returns the line number inside the routine that caused the error.
        ,   ERROR_MESSAGE() AS error_message; --returns the complete text of the error message. The text includes the values supplied for any substitutable parameters, such as lengths, object names, or times.

    END CATCH  

    FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO
        @variable_name
    ,   @description
    ,   @data_type
    ,   @sensitive
    ,   @value;
END

CLOSE Csr;
DEALLOCATE Csr;
```

### Root cause analysis

As I started to write a summary of findings, I discovered the disconnect. As I was loading my temporary table, @EnvironmentVariables, I had originally sourced that directly from `catalog.environment_variables.` To make it more portable, I copied the values out as SELECT statements. This is where I screwed up. When I reconstituted those values, I made the Unicode strings into 'mercan strings. They were written into the sql_variant type column as non-unicode which then blew up when it was passed in the proc for validation. If I correctly preface my strings with the `N` modifier(?) they are stored as nvarchar.

```
FROM
(
    SELECT 'FolderBase','Root for ssis processing','String',CAST(0 AS bit),N'\\myserver\ssisdata'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'AuditConnectionString','Conn to audit db','String',CAST(0 AS bit),N'Data Source=SQLETL01;Initial Catalog=Audit;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;'
) AS S (name, description, type, sensitive, value)
```

Comment: I used a variant of this https://thefirstsql.com/2013/05/28/ssis-2012-easily-copy-environment-variables-to-new-servers-or-new-environments/ to generate my script/ . If I understand correctly, I need to make sure all of my string literals start with `N` but I still have this issue. In fact I get complaints about boolean and datetime but none of my parameters use htese data types. Do you have any insight?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @billinkc excellent answer (surely you knew you you would be the one to answer this question!!) and enrich the knowledge around this....

Here's some sample code, autogenerated from here https://thefirstsql.com/2013/05/28/ssis-2012-easily-copy-environment-variables-to-new-servers-or-new-environments/ that throws the error:

```
DECLARE @var sql_variant

SET @var = '2'
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM [catalog].[environment_variables] 
    WHERE environment_id = @environment_id 
    AND name = N'MyVariable')
EXEC [catalog].[create_environment_variable] 
    @variable_name=N'SystemCd', 
    @sensitive=0, @description=N'', 
    @environment_name=@env_name, 
    @folder_name=@folder, 
    @value=@var, 
    @data_type=N'Int64'
```

Specifically the error is

> Msg 27147, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   internal.check_data_type_value, Line 22 [Batch Start Line 0] The data
>   type of the input value is not compatible with the data type of the
>   'Int64'.

I also had other errors for datetime and boolean

So without going to great lengths understanding the issue, the solution was basically to use a specific datatype rather than `sql_variant` when passing a value into the `@value` parameter.

For Int64 and Boolean you can just hard code the value but for `datetime` you *have* to pre declare a variable of type `datetime` and use it - you can't just pass in a string date literal

This is the first time I've seen a parameter in a stored procedure apparently accept a variety of data types.

```
DECLARE @var sql_variant
DECLARE @var_int int

SET @var = '2'
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM [catalog].[environment_variables] 
    WHERE environment_id = @environment_id 
    AND name = N'MyVariable')
EXEC [catalog].[create_environment_variable] 
    @variable_name=N'SystemCd', 
    @sensitive=0, @description=N'', 
    @environment_name=@env_name, 
    @folder_name=@folder, 
    @value=@var_int, 
    @data_type=N'Int64'
```

Comment: Makes great sense to be explicit instead of using the one-size-fits-all-from-SQL-Server-2000